# Rails.logger is not overriden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 envs: test, and production
in both I have the following under enviroments/*.rb:

```
config.logger = LogStashLogger.new(port: 5228)
```

Problem is , that only on test env i have Rails.logger pointing to this logger and working, and in production env, the Rails.logger is still STDOUT.
I looked and searched for another override, but found nothing.
I even tried to put it on the config/enviroment.rb, but without any luck. Production insists on being STDOUT...

Is this related to nginx/passenger in any way?
Please assist

Tnx!

Comment: how are you detecting value of `config.logger` in production?

Comment: when setting it, i use puts and i see the logstashlogger class. but in the code itself it is railsstdout. like something overrides it after initilization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was rails_12factor in my gemfile (Heroku's gem) that includes
rails_stdout_logging !!!!!

i removed it completely and it solved my problem.